# Captcha on the user_login_form and user_pass form?

Tags: 7, forms, captcha

just checked on my site and it seems that certain login forms do not have captcha. specifically the form named:

1. user-login-form
2. user-pass

I put in user_login_form in the captcha page to make it show up, but it doesnt seem like that is working. am i grabbing the correct form id from the NAME attribute in the form tag?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add captcha to
1. user_login
and 
2. user_login_block(instead of user_login_form)

as shown below:
[image]